# creating a function in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2

I'm a newbie in Objective-C, and I'm trying to add Markers to a mapView in my Apple app.

In my class Map, I'm trying to add a function wich adds markers.

In Map.h I add:

```
- (void)setMarkers:(MKMapView *)mv;
```

And in Map.m:

```
- (void)setMarkers:(MKMapView *)mv
{

CLLocationCoordinate2D newCoord = { 38.989567, -1.856283};
MapPoint *mp = [[MapPoint alloc] initWithCoordinate:newCoord title:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Azam Home"] subTitle:@"Home Sweet Home"];
[mv addAnnotation:mp];

}
```

But when I try to call this function:

```
[setMarkers mv:map];
```

I have this error:

```
Map.m:278:6: Use of undeclared identifier 'setMarkers'
```

What am I missing?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `self`:

```
[self setMarkers:mv];
```

Comment: It also works changing - to + and [Map setMarkers:mv] Thanks!

Comment: Changing - to + makes the method static, but if that works, that's fine. :)

Comment: @SuneTrudslev There are no static methods in Objective-C. Methods declared with a `+` are class methods, not static methods.

Comment: What is the difference, in your opinion, between static and class method?

Comment: Nitpickers will object to the term "static" for class methods in Objective-C, but at the 10,000 foot level (or even the 10 foot level) they're the same.  On close examination there are distinctions in that a class method is still a dynamic method, only one "sent" to the class object rather than a class instance.  "Static", on the other hand, basically represents a "hard coded" linkage where the address of the method is effectively stored in the calling instruction.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, which I guess in the grand pragmatic scheme of things, makes them the same. In the dynamic messaging nature of Objective-C not possible to hard code a linkage, but on the other hand, but I am sure that the OP got the gist of it, even if I used the wrong term :)